# Custom SVG cursor wont click element below

Tags: svg, html5-canvas, raphael, game-physics

I'm trying to make a simple game using Raphaël.js and I came across a problem very early in development, where I made a sight for aiming by attaching a circle to the cursors position, but when I click the target it doesn't trigger the targets click event , but the aim.

```
background.mousemove(function(e){
    ePointer.attr({
        'fill':'none',
        'stroke':'none'
    }); 

    nx = e.clientX - $('#canvas').offset().left;
    ny = e.clientY - $('#canvas').offset().top;

    pointer.attr({
        'fill':'none',
        'stroke':'#CC0000',
        'stroke-width': 3,
        'cx':nx,
        'cy':ny
    });

});
background.click(function(e){
    pointer.animate(bClick);
    pointer.animate(bUnclick.delay(250));
    pointer.animate(bUnclick);
});

enemies.mousemove(function(e){
    pointer.attr({
        'fill':'none',
        'stroke':'none'
    });
    nx = e.clientX - $('#canvas').offset().left;
    ny = e.clientY - $('#canvas').offset().top;
    ePointer.attr({
        'cx':nx,
        'cy':ny,
        'fill': '#00CC00',
        'stroke':'none'
    });
});
```

The jsfiddle link will say more then I could : http://jsfiddle.net/Uuqgx/6/

Thanks in advanced,
    Giovanni.

Answer (score 0):

Raphael's paper object has a method called [Paper.getElementByPoint(x, y)](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.getElementByPoint) that gets the top object under the mouse. Of course, this alone doesn't help you since the circle is still under the mouse. However, if you hide it, run this method inputing the current mouse coordinates, then unhide the circle, you'll get the rectangle under it without any visible interruption:

```
ePointer.click(function(e){
    score++
    tScore.attr({
        'text': 'Score: ' + score 
    });
    nx = e.clientX - document.getElementById('canvas').offsetLeft;
    ny = e.clientY - document.getElementById('canvas').offsetTop;

    //get targeted rectangle
    this.hide();    
    console.log(paper.getElementByPoint(nx, ny));
    this.show();

    ePointer.animate(eClick);
    ePointer.animate(eUnclick.delay(150));
    ePointer.animate(eUnclick);
});
```

Here I've just logged the targeted rectangle to the console, but once you've found it like this you can do whatever you want to it.

Note that offset().Top becomes offsetTop in order for this to work in jsFiddle, since jQuery isn't present in the fiddle.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uuqgx/7/).